# Web app sencha touch error

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have some problems in this part of JavaScript code in Sencha Touch, and I don't know how to resolve it.

```
new Ext.application({
  name: 'TouchStart',
  launch: function() {    
    this.viewport = new Ext.Panel({
      fullscreen: true,
      bodyPadding: 5,
      dockedItems: [            {
        dock : 'top',
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        title: 'Touch Start'
      }, {
        dock : 'top',
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
            text: 'Hello Button'
        }]
      }],    
      html: 'Hello Panel'
    });
  }
});
```

The console shows:

```
This.viewport = new Ext.Panel({
> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

salam
you must to change your code `Ext.Panel` to
 `Ext.create('Ext.Panel',...........`